# Jupyter Notebook commands doesn't work?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In the help, it says Ctr + Enter to run the current cell, but it doesn't work. I am on CentOs 7.

Is this really an issue?

Comment: Does it work if you press the run button instead?

Comment: Using mouse to click "run cell, select below" works.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it works for me